# Create a function that generates a matrix of (n,n) in which the sum of the elements of each column is equal to 1

Tags: r, matrix

I want to create a function that generates a matrix with random values larger than 0 and lower than 1 and the sum of the elements of each column should be equal to 1.

This is what I tried but I always get the sum of the rows equal to 1 and not the columns. I can't figure out why...

```
generar_matriz_columnas_suma_uno <- function(num_filas, num_columnas) {
  matriz <- matrix(0, nrow = num_filas, ncol = num_columnas)
  
  for (j in 1:num_columnas) {
    # Generate a random column with values between 0 and 1
    columna_aleatoria <- runif(num_columnas, min = 0, max = 1)
    
    # Normalize the column to sum up to 1
    suma_columna <- sum(columna_aleatoria)
    columna_normalizada <- columna_aleatoria / suma_columna
    
    # Assign the normalized column to the matrix
    matriz[, j] <- columna_normalizada
  }
  
  return(matriz)
}
```

Comment: try :  runif(num_filas, min = 0, max = 1)

Comment: still the sum of the rows is equal to 1 but not of the columns (to clarify, the rows do not have to be equal to 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
gen_matrix <- function(nrow, ncol){
  m <- matrix(0, nrow, ncol)

  for (j in seq(ncol)){
    x <- runif(nrow, 0, 1)
    m[, j] <- x / sum(x)
  }

  return(m)
}
```

output:

```r
set.seed(1)
m <- gen_matrix(nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
m

#            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]      [,4]       [,5]
# [1,] 0.11442486 0.28120698 0.09263532 0.1479177 0.42655337
# [2,] 0.16037227 0.29569494 0.07940491 0.2132783 0.09681138
# [3,] 0.24687958 0.20683781 0.30898271 0.2947974 0.29739176
# [4,] 0.39140550 0.19692041 0.17274740 0.1129476 0.05729715
# [5,] 0.08691779 0.01933986 0.34622966 0.2310590 0.12194633

colSums(m)
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: thank you! What if it is not a squared matrix?

Comment: Check edit, you can specify in the funciton

Answer (score 4):

You can try `runif` to generate random values within the interval `0` to `1` and `proportions` to normalize the values such that the columns sum up to `1`, e.g.,

```
set.seed(0)
n <- 5
mat <- proportions(matrix(runif(n^2), n), 2)
```

and you will see

```
> mat
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]      [,4]       [,5]
[1,] 0.29737345 0.06048053 0.04077106 0.2293174 0.28778047
[2,] 0.08805116 0.26940978 0.13591697 0.1482527 0.34599211
[3,] 0.12340818 0.28328994 0.11650495 0.2137614 0.07852704
[4,] 0.18997648 0.19816055 0.45334752 0.2954651 0.24122469
[5,] 0.30119073 0.18865920 0.25345950 0.1132034 0.04647569

> colSums(mat)
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: thank you! What if it is not a squared matrix?

Comment: @AyozeAlfageme If you want a `mxn` matrix, you can run `matrix(runif(m*n), m)` instead

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `matrix` filled with `runif` and divide the columns by `colSums`.

```
fun <- function(nrow, ncol) {
  M <- matrix(runif(nrow*ncol), nrow, ncol)
  sweep(M, 2, colSums(M), `/`)
}

set.seed(0)
fun(2, 3)
#          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#[1,] 0.7715476 0.3937914 0.8182865
#[2,] 0.2284524 0.6062086 0.1817135
```

Some variants might be.

```
fun2 <- function(nrow, ncol) {
  M <- matrix(runif(nrow*ncol), ncol, nrow)
  t(M / rowSums(M))
}

fun3 <- function(nrow, ncol) {
  M <- matrix(runif(nrow*ncol), nrow, ncol)
  M / colSums(M)[col(M)]
}
```